# Micronaut HttpClient throws Client '/conversations': Not Found when the previous test executes successfully

Tags: java, testing, micronaut

I am facing problems when using Micronaut's HttpClient during Testing

I have dozens of tests in my application that all work fine but suddenly my new tests are throwing errors when executing, here is my class:

```
@MicronautTest
class ConversationControllerTest {
    @Client("/conversations")
    @Inject
    HttpClient httpClient;

    @MockBean(ConversationService.class)
    ConversationService conversationService() {
        return mock(ConversationService.class);
    }

    @MockBean(JwtTokenService.class)
    JwtTokenService jwtTokenService() {
        return mock(JwtTokenService.class);
    }

    @Inject
    JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

    @Inject
    ConversationService conversationService;

    @Test
    void createConversationReturnsOK() {
        Instant expirationTime = Instant.now().plusSeconds(180L);

        String mockJwt = JWT.create()
                .withExpiresAt(Date.from(expirationTime))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256("fake secret"));

        DecodedJWT decodedJWTMock = JWT.decode(mockJwt);

        when(jwtTokenService.verifyJwtToken(any(DecodedJWT.class))).thenReturn(true);
        when(jwtTokenService.decode(mockJwt)).thenReturn(decodedJWTMock);
        when(conversationService.createConversation(null)).thenReturn(1L);

        var request = HttpRequest.POST("", null)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + mockJwt);

        var response = httpClient.toBlocking().exchange(request);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    void getConversationReturnsNotFound() {
        Instant expirationTime = Instant.now().plusSeconds(180L);

        String mockJwt = JWT.create()
                .withExpiresAt(Date.from(expirationTime))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256("fake secret"));

        DecodedJWT decodedJWTMock = JWT.decode(mockJwt);

        Long mockConversationId = 2L;

        when(jwtTokenService.verifyJwtToken(any(DecodedJWT.class))).thenReturn(true);
        when(jwtTokenService.decode(mockJwt)).thenReturn(decodedJWTMock);
        when(conversationService.conversationExists(mockConversationId)).thenReturn(false);

//        var request = HttpRequest.GET(String.format("conversations/%d", mockConversationId))
        var request = HttpRequest.GET(String.format("/%d", 2))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + mockJwt);

        System.out.println(request.getUri());

        var response = httpClient.toBlocking().exchange(request);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, response.getStatus());
    }
```

The test 'CreateConversationReturnsOk' executes succesfully whereas all the other tests fail.

I have two endpoints in the controller and the root endpoint is '/conversations'
and the other one is rootEndpoint/{conversationId}.

Is there something I am missing?